# There is some problem with code, It's not doing what it supposed to do. why is that?

Tags: python, http, post, request

I am new to python & these http thing.

I am sure that this code having some issue as I am sending request through `postman` it's working fine but with python request it is not working. It's not showing any error though. I think I am missing something.

```
import requests
import json

url="http://localhost:8080/api/v1/post_info"

json ={
    "vaishnavi": 22,
    "uni_didi": 34,
    "stokes": 31
}

r=requests.post(url, json)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: "Not working" isn't a question. What is it supposed to do, what is it doing instead?

Comment: Try `requests.post(url, json=json)`

Comment: Is the API supposed to accept json, or plain form data?

Comment: @Barmar worked man. Can you tell what happened.

Comment: @JohnGordon json

Comment: @Tyler durden `json` is not the second parameter in the `post` function signature.

Comment: @DanLuba can you provide me a link where can I read more about this. Like how many arguments it take or of what type. I don't know anything. Just I am reading random codes on web by following anology trying to work.

Comment: @Tyler durden https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Some good places to look for info when you get stuck are: https://www.w3schools.com/python, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/, and you can always just google "<package> <method> docs" to find the documentation for a particular package.